# MySQL inner join 3 таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

У меня есть таблиц с данными о фотографии, таблица с списком лайков от различных пользователей ко всем фотографиям и таблица с комментариями к фотографиям. Мне нужно вывести количество лайков и комментариев к последним 12 фотографиям. 
Проблема состоит в том что при склейке 3х таблиц количество комментариев и лайков возводится в квадрат

Структура таблиц

> comments:
>   id (PK A_I), photoId, userId, text
>
> likes:
>   id (PK A_I), photoId, userId
>
> photos:
>   photoId (PK A_I), name, path

Update: если я захочу добавить дислайки, для них лучше заводить аналогичную лайкам таблицу или добавить столбец (лайк/дислайк) ?

Update2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `photos` 
RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT photoId, COUNT(photoId) as likesCount
            FROM likes
           GROUP BY photoId) as x
ON photos.photoId = x.photoID
RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT photoId, COUNT(photoId) as commentsCount
            FROM comments
           GROUP BY photoId) as y
ON photos.photoId = y.photoID
WHERE 1
```

Comment: запрос то ваш где?

Comment: *при склейке 3х таблиц количество комментариев и лайков возводится в квадрат* Считайте отдельно по каждой таблице в подзапросах, а потом уже связывайте результат с основной таблицей. *если я захочу добавить дислайки, для них лучше заводить аналогичную лайкам таблицу или добавить столбец (лайк/дислайк) ?* одного поля достаточно. +1 - лайк, -1 соответственно дислайк.

Comment: добавил запрос. как сделать чтобы если нет на фото лайков, то ставилось дефолтное значение 0 и эта фотография показывалась при RIGHT JOINe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было соединять таблицу в подзапросах. Так же использовать LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `photos` 
left OUTER JOIN ( SELECT photoId, COUNT(photoId) as likesCount
            FROM likes
           GROUP BY photoId) as x
ON photos.photoId = x.photoID
left OUTER JOIN ( SELECT photoId, COUNT(photoId) as commentsCount
            FROM comments
           GROUP BY photoId) as y
ON photos.photoId = y.photoID
```